# Mathematica classify NeuralNetwork default parameters

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, implementation-details

We have trained a Neural Network on Mathemetica classify with one hidden layer and received good classification results. We would like to know the default parameters beside it has one hidden layer? Such as network architecture(fully-connected or convolution), optimizer,active function,learning rate..

Answer (score 1):

Lets define a Classifer that uses a Neural Net as a method with some training data.

```
train = {{1, 2, 3} -> "Red", {2, 6, 2} -> "Blue", {4, 9, 2} -> 
  "Green"}
classModel=Classify[train, Method -> "NeuralNetwork", 
 TargetDevice -> "GPU"];
```

We can then Use Keys[] and Values[] to explore the options that 
Classify[] uses.

```
Keys[classModel[[1, "Model"]]]
Values[classModel[[1, "Model"]]]
```

We can specify the network, training and even the options to view the learning rate, optimiser method etc

```
ClassNN = classModel[[1, "Model", "Network"]]
TrainingNN = classModel[[1, "Model", "Training"]]
OptionsNN = classModel[[1, "Model", "Options"]]
```